# orderby="random" same results being displayed every time

Tags: channel-entries, orderby, random

I am trying to select 3 random entries from a few channels.  I have:

```
{exp:channel:entries limit="3" channel="X|Y|Z" status="open" orderby="random" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination" dynamic="no" cache="no"}

    ....

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The issue I have is that the same 3 entries continue to be displayed, in varying order.  I assume the query must be cached somewhere?  I can't figure it out though.

I do have memcached enabled for EE, and I think this is where the issue lies. If I disable caching, every refresh of the page actually displays 3 random items.

Is there a way to prevent EE from caching this query? In my 'Template Manager', this particular template has "No" for "Enable Caching?"

Comment: try {exp:channel:entries limit="3" channel="X|Y|Z" status="open" orderby="random" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination" dynamic="no" cache="no" random}

Answer (score 2):

So it looks like I have to disable "Cache Dynamic Channel Queries?" in Admin->Channel Administration->Global Channel Preferences

For random ordering to function properly

Comment: If this is the correct answer for your initial question please mark it as answer.